# Pandas sum and agg(sum) yields different values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a pandas dataset which i want to groupby and agg with sum function.

When I use just `df['col1'].sum()`, I get different result then after agg:

```
data_grouped = data[['col2','col3','col1']].groupby(['col2','col3'])['col1'].sum()
```

I have already tried using `dropna=False`, but I get the same result. The sum after agg is lower then just simple sum in dataset.

Where can be the mistake?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that reproduces your poblem, including the expected result.

Comment: I am not able to provide such example, because I cannot share underlying data and I have no idea where is the problem, so I cannot replicate any similar example. Expected result is to have explanations for the differences.

Comment: Your question is rather confusing: You mention `agg` several times but there is no code with `agg` in it in the question. You should at least provide (1) the exact codes for which you compare the results and (2) tell us what kind of data you are summing up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Check for missing values in 'col1'
missing_values = data['col1'].isnull().sum()
print("Number of missing values in 'col1':", missing_values)

data_cleaned = data.dropna(subset=['col1'])
data_grouped = data_cleaned.groupby(['col2', 'col3'])['col1'].sum()

data_filled = data.fillna({'col1': 0})
data_grouped = data_filled.groupby(['col2', 'col3'])['col1'].sum()

data_grouped = data.groupby(['col2', 'col3'])['col1'].agg(np.nansum)
```